# Are Meals part of expenses?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I drove from Pittsburg to Philly to meet with customers.  I left my home at 6:00 A.M. and did not get back from Philly until 11:45 P.M. that night.  I was very busy and all 3 of my meals were takeout from fast food places in Philly as I went from Customer to customer.

Should I write down meal expenses on my tax forms? I have the receipt.

Comment: Were you with a customer for any of the meals?

Comment: where's your office? Are you self-employed? Do you have contracts with these customers? It's impossible to answer as is.

Comment: What tax forms are you talking about?

Comment: No, I did not dine with customers. I was eating fast food while driving. I need to file Form 2106. I am working for a small start up company.

Comment: *Use Form 2106 if you were an Armed Forces reservist, a qualified performing artist, a fee-basis state or local government official, or an employee with impairment-related work expenses.* - does any of that apply to you?

Comment: No, it does not apply to me.

Comment: Then you cannot file form 2106. If you're an employee - you should request reimbursements per diem from your employer.

Comment: Being self-employed might complicate this, but most companies have very explicit rules about what they do and don't consider a business expense. And if the company expenses it, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you are an employee of a company:

You can be reimbursed by your employer for lodging, miles, tolls, parking, and meals. They will have rules regarding daily limits. They will also have procedures regarding is approval need in advance, and deadlines and procedures for submitting the required paperwork. Their rules are in place to meet their accounting rules, and to follow IRS regulations.

For most employees this isn't something that appears on their individual tax form. The money they spend is reimbursed, so it isn't taxable income. That also means the employee doesn't claim it as a work related deduction.

It is possible to receive more money then you directly spend. For example if you claim miles you can receive more money than you spent on gas because the amount is also supposed to cover wear and tear on the vehicle.

The money can be considered taxable income if the expenses don't fall under the IRS rules. This generally happens when the company is paying you for normal living expenses.

Note: The tax law changes in 2017 eliminated the [miscellaneous itemized deduction](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p529)

> Deductions for Unreimbursed Employee Expenses
>
> You can no longer claim any miscellaneous itemized deductions that are
> subject to the 2%-of-AGI limitation, including unreimbursed employee
> expenses. However, you may be able to deduct certain unreimbursed
> employee business expenses if you fall into one of the following
> categories of employment listed under Unreimbursed Employee Expenses
> next, or are an eligible educator as defined under Educator Expenses ,
> later.

Notice there was no discussion of reporting the expense by the company. If you own the company then your reporting requirements are more complex.